# How can I use the onmouseover event on a nav using its class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, onmouseover

I am new to javascript and am trying to get a mouseover on a nav to make it change color of the nav bar to green. I coded what I thought would work but nothing is happening. The total length of the entire html page is huge, so I am just adding the code I believe affects the nav mouseover. I'm also using getelementsbyclass[2] because it's the 3rd element with the class.

```
    <nav class="group" onmouseover="func1()">
       <ol>
          <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="artists.html">artists</a></li>
          <li><a href="schedule.html">schedule</a></li>
          <li><a href="venuetravel.html">venue/travel</a></li>
          <li><a href="register.html">register</a></li>
       </ol>
    </nav>

    <script src="_/js/myscript.js"></script>

    <!--myscript.js-->

    function func1() {
       document.getElementsByClassName("group")[2].style.background-color = "green";
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use CSS to turn the background color green for the navigation, instead of using scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, there are many mistakes. The first mistake is in this line of `myscript.js`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("group")[2].style.background-color = "green";
```

There is no `background-color` property in JavaScript DOM. Instead, this is how it will look: `backgroundColor`. So, now `myscript.js` should look like this:

```
    function func1() {
       document.getElementsByClassName("group")[2].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
```

The second issue is in the same line, `document.getElementsByClassName("group")[2].style.backgroundColor = "green";`. `document.getElementsByClassName("group")` will return an array containing all the elements that have the class of `group`. In your HTML code, only one element, the `<nav>` tag has this class. Since array indexing begins with 0, there is no `document.getElementsByClassName("group")[2]` element. Only the first element with the index of `0` exists in this array. So change that index. Now, your JavaScript code should look like this:

```
    function func1() {
       document.getElementsByClassName("group")[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the Javascript syntax will be

```
document.getElementsByClassName("group")[0].style.backgroundColor = "green"
```

And with the code you provided, I just changed **("group")[3]** to **("group")[0]** and it just works.